iam new to C. Why the third printf dont show until i put some number in the program
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double pesoItem1;
    double pesoItem2;
    double cantItem1;
    double cantItem2;
    double prom;

    printf("Ingrese peso del item 1 :");
    scanf("%lf",&pesoItem1);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad del primer item :\n");
    scanf("%lf ", &cantItem1);

    //this print dont show until i put a number on the console and hit enter.
    printf("Ingrese el peso del item 2 :\n");
    scanf("%lf", &pesoItem2);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad del item 2 :\n");
    scanf("%lf", &cantItem2);

    prom = ((pesoItem1 * cantItem1) + (pesoItem2 *cantItem2)) / (cantItem1 + cantItem2);

    printf("el promedio es %.2lf", prom);
    return 0;
}

Write a C program that accepts two item's weight and number of purchases (floating point values) and calculates their average value.
I put the \n try the fflush and others things and nothings seems to work, but if i copy the code from the web it works , and i thinks that the code is the same as mine ,but mine not work
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double wi1, ci1, wi2, ci2, result; // Declare variables for weights and counts

    // Prompt user for weight and count of item 1
    printf("Weight - Item1: ");
    scanf("%lf", &wi1);

    // Prompt user for count of item 1
    printf("No. of item1: ");
    scanf("%lf", &ci1);
    
    // Prompt user for weight and count of item 2
    printf("Weight - Item2: ");
    scanf("%lf", &wi2);
    
    // Prompt user for count of item 2
    printf("No. of item2: ");
    scanf("%lf", &ci2);
    
    // Calculate average value
    result = ((wi1 * ci1) + (wi2 * ci2)) / (ci1 + ci2);
    
    // Print the average value
    printf("Average Value = %f\n", result);
    
    return 0;
}


Because of the space after %lf in "%lf ".  That space means that scanf() continues reading until you type something that isn't white space (not a blank, tab or newline).  Note that the code from the web does not have the trailing space in the format.

thanks it work , i was thinking of buffered idk what bla bla ,that i was seeing on the web, thks again mate..
